# Contours created in Global Mapper have many intersections/crossovers

Tags: contour, global-mapper

Working o creating contours from Terrain Grid using Global Mapper with 0.5 m intervals. Generated contours have many crossovers/intersections.
Any suggestion on how to prevent the issue?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a matter of resolution. Maybe try to increase your intervals (to 1m, for instance), or find a higher resolution dataset for your area.

Comment: Probably bad DEM

Comment: Can you post the original elevation data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the suggestions, DEM is fine and increasing intervals didn't resolve the issue but I was able to find what caused the issue, for some reason the Global Mapper package files option makes that problem. [image]

Turning this option off makes contours nice and smooth looking without the intersections.[image]